# How to make background change colour in a flashing effect

Tags: android

I am trying to make the background flash when music plays in my app but it isn't working as expected.

The music plays when a button is pressed. The background should be yellow when the music is off but flash quickly between yellow and purple when the music is playing.

At the moment it is yellow when off, changes to some dull grey when the music is playing and does not return to yellow when the music is off.

```
public class InstaRave extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "InstaRave";
private static int isPlaying = 0; // 0 is not playing 1 is playing
private MediaPlayer mp;
public static int mPurple = color.mPurple;
public static int mYellow = color.mYellow;
public static int currentBackground = mYellow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insta_rave);


    final Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.raveButton);
    final RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.topLevelLayout);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rave_mk);

    Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");

    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (isPlaying){
                case 0:
                    changeBackground(mRelativeLayout);
                    startMusic();
                    isPlaying = 1;
                    rave();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    changeBackground(mRelativeLayout);
                    stopMusic();
                    isPlaying = 0;
                    rave();
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Ooops something went wrong");
            }
        }

        private void stopMusic(){
            Log.v(TAG, "Stopping sound...");
            mp.stop();
            //isPlaying = 0;
            mp.prepareAsync();
        }

        private void startMusic(){
            Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
            mp.start();
            //isPlaying = 1;
        }

        private void rave(){
            Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(isPlaying));
            if (isPlaying == 1){
                Log.v(TAG, "Raving....");
                new Rave().execute();
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "End the rave the po po is here...");
            }
        }

    });
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}

private void changeBackground(RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout){
    if (currentBackground == mYellow){
        currentBackground = mPurple;
        mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(currentBackground);
        Log.v(TAG, "Background is: " + String.valueOf(currentBackground));
    }
    currentBackground = mYellow;
    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(currentBackground);
    Log.v(TAG, "Background is: " + String.valueOf(currentBackground));
}

private class Rave extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    final RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLevelLayout);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (isPlaying ==1){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
                publishProgress();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress){
        changeBackground(mRelativeLayout);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.insta_rave, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your changeBackground() method to this:

```
private void changeBackground(RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout){
  if (currentBackground == mYellow){
      currentBackground = mPurple;
      mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(currentBackground);
      Log.v(TAG, "Background is: " + String.valueOf(currentBackground));
  }
  else
  {
     currentBackground = mYellow;
     mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(currentBackground);
     Log.v(TAG, "Background is: " + String.valueOf(currentBackground));
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly the same as what I am using. Can you describe what you've changed?

Comment: OK I see what you've done! Yes this does work. If anyone else couldn't see it the trick here is to implement the If Then Else statement correctly as @Al0x suggests. In my original code I did not implement the Else portion correctly. Thanks. Answer accepted!